# Why Multicollinearity is a problem in machine learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, regression, feature-selection, correlation, collinearity

Is only a subset of algorithms are affected by the multicollinearity problem or all the machine learning algorithms?
What is the solution for this?

Comment: [Is there an intuitive explanation why multicollinearity is a problem in linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/is-there-an-intuitive-explanation-why-multicollinearity-is-a-problem-in-linear-r)

Comment: [For what specific models is multicolinearity a problem in the context of making predictions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/465500/for-what-specific-models-is-multicolinearity-a-problem-in-the-context-of-making)

Comment: [Why is multicollinearity not checked in modern statistics/machine learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168622/why-is-multicollinearity-not-checked-in-modern-statistics-machine-learning/168631#168631)

Comment: Like the above comments, what is the "problem" and what algorithm(s) have the problem you are stating? But looking here and on crossvalidated, there are lots of questions on multicollinearity, what problems it may or may not have, etc. Happy to help if there are specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Only a subset of machine learning algorithms are affected by multicollinearity. Algorithms from the [general linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model) (GLM) family are the ones most likely to have issues with multicollinearity because of the algorithm structures:

$$ Y = XB + U$$

Other machine learning algorithms have different structures, and thus do not have similar issues with multicollinearity. For example, tree-based algorithms automatically do feature selection during model fitting and will only choose one of the multicollinear features at a time.

The most common solutions for multicollinearity are:

- Choose an algorithm robust to multicollinearity.
- Test for multicollinearity, then choose an algorithm based on the result.
- Ignore multicollinearity, then choose not to do any use cases where multicollinearity is an issue (e.g., statistical inference).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Brian